# java createText without Ctrl C, Ctrl V

Tags: java, hotkeys, shortcut

I have tried to create a text box with

```
protected FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
Text idInput = toolkit.createText(parent, " ", SWT.BORDER);
```

Then, there is just <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, but no <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> function, how can I get these `HotKey` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system clipboard. This will allow you to copy and paste from the Java application to native applications too!

Create a new `ActionListener` that uses the `Clipboard`.

```
public class ClipboardActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    private final JTextField;

    public ClipboardActionListener(JTextField text)
    {
        this.text= text;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Clipboard system = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(text.getText());
        system.setContents(selection, selection)
    }
}
```

And register the key strokes when you create the text field.

```
KeyStroke copy = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK, false);
textField.registerKeyboardAction(new ClipboardActionListener(textField), copy, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
```